# Why does outlook strip formatting from my messages?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I often find myself sending mails that are carefully formatted, with tables, colors, bolding, different fonts etc.  When people reply to me, I see that the replies are stripped of most formatting, and in fact, when I look in my sent mail, I see the formatting stripped.

For instance, this is what I sent:
[image]

and this is how it ended up in my sent mail:

[image]

The `c` remained in bold, but the table is gone, and so is the highlighting of b.

This happens whether I'm sending the mail as HTML or RTF.

Why is Outlook doing that?

I am using Outlook 2013, but I've was seeing this in Outlook 2010 as well, and IIRC, also 2007.

Answer (score 5):

This was because of this setting in outlook:

[image]

When I unchecked that, and set the message format to HTML, the formatting stopped being stripped away.

Comment: Even with reduce message size option set I do not have this issue in Outlook 2016. I have a feeling that the "set to HTML" was your issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you send your email do you make sure you have selected `Aa HTML` instead of `Aa Plain Text`?
Also when people reply, if they reply using Plain Text formatting there is every chance it will strip out your HTML.

Comment: I tried both HTML and RTF.  I rarely send as Plain Text.  I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Also note that the `c` remained in **bold**, which can't happen in Plain Text.

Comment: have the emails remained as HTML on the reply as well now?

Comment: yes, they have.

Comment: good stuff, sorry i couldnt help, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to paste the table as picture. You can either copy and paste the table within Outlook itself, would would give the option of pasting as picture, or you can paste special > paste as picture.

Similarly, all formatting can be done in excel and the table pasted as picture in outlook.

Comment: the table is just an example. I have text that is colored, bolded, italicized, fonted, resized, and most of this is stripped away.

Comment: @NathanFellman With respect to your own answer, I have the option already checked on my computer but it does not remove any formatting.

Comment: Very strange.  It could be that it's a combination of that and some other setting.

Comment: Tables as pictures break my heart, please don't do this!

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem.  What I do is the following on Outlook 2010:

**New E-mail> Insert> Screenshot> Screen Clipping**, then using your mouse draw a box to the area you want to copy and Outlook will insert the highlighted area into the new email.

I assume it will be similar to other versions of Outlook.